# Issue with session closing in java server page

Tags: jsp

I have a problem with session in my project.
when i sign in i made a session

```
session.setAttribute("userid",userid);
```

and when i logout i have logout page as:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Logged out</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCFFFF">
    <%@  page errorPage="errorpage.jsp" language="java" %>
    <%
    session.invalidate();
    %>
        <center>
    <BR><BR><BR><BR><b>You have logged out successfully.
        <BR><BR>Return to Exam Portal? <a href="signup.html">Click here</a></b>
        </center>
</body>
</html>
```

And in every page i check if session is null or not by including header file as:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*,java.util.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Online Exam Portal</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
if(session.getAttribute("userid")==null)
{
%>
<jsp:forward page="signup.html"/>
<%
}
%>
<img src="exam_header01.jpg"/>
<br />
Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("userid")%>
<a href="ChangePassword.jsp">Change Password</a> 
<a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a> 

<hr/>
```

Every time I signin browse page and logout i am redirected to signup page and even when i try to enter through url or any link after pressing back button i am redirected which is expected
 **But the problem is:**
After Pressing back button and refreshing the page 3 times i get a message :

> To display the webpage again the web browser needs to resend the
>   information you have previously submitted
>   And after that i am getting my session back.
>   So is there any solution to this.
>  **Thank you in Advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with your session but a problem how you handle POST request in your app. When you do a POST request the browser sends form data to the browser. If you use the browser navigation to go back an try to refresh the page the browser tries to send the same request to the server, and because the last request was a POST request the browser warns you that it will resend the form data again. The browser shows this warning to make sure that you really want to submit the form again and wants you to explicitly say `Yes` (You should actually always say `No`, unless you know what you re doing / what are the consequences).

So why is the browser then asking to confirm a re-submit on refresh?

Let's say you are in a shopping site and want, have put some articles in your shopping cart and have checked out by clicking `Buy now!`. The form data is sent to the server and you get the confirmation and the money changes pockets. Now you go back a do a refresh - let's say to see if your cart is now empty - what happens? the browser sends another `Buy now!`, do you really want that? I don't think! Usually you want to buy stuff only when you hit `Buy now!` and not because you just refreshed the page.

Another example related to authentication. Let's say you are browsing a site where you need to be authenticated (username/password for example). After you are done, you hit `log out`. then you leave the computer to another person. That person then uses browser navigation to go back to the log in page and then hits refresh, what happens? The browser asks/warns that it will send form data again, which happens to be your authentication information. And now the other person can surf the site with your identity. Do you really want that? I don't think so.

So to summarize, it's bad practice to write directly to the output of a response after a POST request. Instead you need to trigger a redirect, so that the browser can request the next page by itself by sending a GET request.

This paradigm is called [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)